# Javascript Object-like-string to Object

Tags: javascript, object, eval

I am storing validation rules in a HTML attribute.

The validation rule in a string literal that looks like this:

```
'{required:true, minlength:2, maxlength:100}'
```

To convert it to a javascript object I can use `eval(string_literal)`

However, `eval` is...unpleasant.

Is there an alternate to using eval to convert a *object like string* to an *object*?

A constraint is I cant use JSON.

Comment: "A constraint is I cant use JSON"... why? It's a perfect use case for JSON. Change your string to quote the keys and it is valid JSON.

Comment: Well it's not JSON anyway, since keys in JSON have to be double-quoted....  Where are you getting these strings from?

Comment: If it were a valid JSON string then you could use `JSON.parse('{"required":true, "minlength":2, "maxlength":100}')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `eval` with *well-controlled data from a source you trust* is fine. The startup cost of the parser is negligible at worst. Naturally, using `eval` with poorly-controlled data from sources you *don't* trust is a Bad Idea<sup>tm</sup>.

If you don't use `eval`, I'm afraid there's no real shortcut, you'll have to parse the string yourself. If it's really just a simple list as shown, a couple of `split` calls with regular expressions would do it, a full-on parser wouldn't be needed.

Quick off-the-cuff example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ecaqeg/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ecaqeg/1/edit)):

```
(function() {

  var data = '{required:true, minlength:2, maxlength:100}';
  var entries, index, entry, parts;

  entries = data.substring(1, data.length - 2).split(/, ?/);

  for (index = 0; index < entries.length; ++index) {
    entry = entries[index];
    parts = entry.split(/: ?/);
    display("Key '" + parts[0] + "', value '" + parts[1] + "'");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

})();
```

Naturally that's full of assumptions (most notably that values will never be strings containing commas or colons), but again, if the data is simple enough, you can avoid a full parser.